# How can riders in the Northern Hemisphere connect with riders and riding organizations in Australia and the Southern Hemisphere?

Tags: discussion

Are there any particular Australian riding organizations that an American riding org. can partner with?

Any particular Aussie or New Zealand riding blogs? How about Chilean or Argentinian? African?

Do Southern Hemisphere riders outside of Australia & New Zealand speak English? Would they want to communicate with North American riders? If so, what information might they be looking for from us?

-- I ask these questions out of general curiosity, but also because Stack Exchange Bicycles wants to make some inroads south of the equator. Any ideas how we can do this are much appreciated.

Comment: I'm quite supportive of your goals here, but this sure seems like a list question...

Comment: Connect? In what way is that not already being done?

Comment: @wdypdx22 - you're right! I just did some quick, rough, math, and it appears .0005 of the US population has visited Bikes.SE between Jul 1 - Now vs. .0007 of the Australian population. In other terms, there are roughly 10 US visits for every 1 Australian visit. So yes, we are "connecting." But we (I) can do better and I want to. I'd appreciate any ideas you may have about how we can get Down Under.

Comment: This sounds like a question for meta since you are asking about Stack Exchange making inroads.

Comment: I agree, this belongs on meta; I've voted to close and migrate there.

Answer (score 2):

I live in Victoria, Australia. The biggest bicycle group around here is [Bicycle Network](http://www.bv.com.au/).

They organise group rides, advocate for better facilities, provide cycling insurance and generally provide information and support to the cycling community.

Comment: This is helpful. Stand by. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bicycles Network is great, as Mac points out. If you're interested in racing you need a licence and to be a club member.

Regarding blogs, there's [Cycling Tips](http://www.cyclingtipsblog.com) which is quite popular world wide and has information on group rides.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a national bike group in australia. There's an official federation, Cycling Australia, which mainly concerned about the sport itself.

Afaik, these organisations exist in state level, where they have members and influence. You can contact bq.org.au (Bicycle Queensland) www.bikesa.asn.au and(Bicycle South Australia) in addition to bicycle network in Victoria (maybe some New South Welsh can add theirs).